# Tailscale: SSH works with manually compiled Openssh, but not system installed Openssh

Tags: ssh

(This question should be tagged with "Tailscale", but that doesn't exist yet - requires knowledge of Tailscale)

I have a standard Ubuntu 20.04 laptop, connecting via ssh to a remote Raspberry Pi (port 22). At the remote location, there is port forwarding on the router (59995->22).

Note: I have removed `~/.ssh/config` during testing.

SSH always connects successfully, using:

`ssh user@public_ip -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -p 59995`

However, when I use the Tailscale IP, it never connects, just hangs for 120s then times out:

`ssh user@tailscale-ip -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa` (does not work)

However, if I manually compile OpenSSH v8.2, and use that version, instead of the /usr/bin/ssh binary, then it works perfectly! Even though /usr/bin/ssh is also v8.2

`./ssh user@tailscale-ip -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa` (this works!)

Recap: the system binary works fine with "normal" ssh, but not with ssh-via-tailscale. However a manually compiled (same) version of Openssh works fine with both regular ssh, and ssh-over-tailsale. Does anyone know what might be causing this?

### Additional Notes

I don't think it's any obvious problem with the tailscale network: i.e if I probe via tailscale IP then `nmap` scan shows correct ports are open, and I can `netcat` directly to `tailscale_ip:22`, it is receving and responding.

`diff ~/openssh-8.2p1/ssh /usr/bin/ssh` shows that the binary's differ. (huge size difference too, about 3MB vs 0.7MB)

`/usr/bin/ssh -V` : OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.4, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020

`~/openssh-8.2p1/ssh -V` : OpenSSH_8.2p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020

Log of `/usr/bin/ssh -vvv user@tailscale_ip -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa` (ip redacted)

```
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.4, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 100.1.1.1 is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to 100.1.1.1 [100.1.1.1] port 22.
< 2 minute hang here >
ssh: connect to host 100.1.1.1 port 22: Connection timed out
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue because my ssh client didn't show Tailscale's 2FA message, with default ACL policy for `ssh/action` set to `"check"`.

Try checking ACL settings for your user/tag?
What is action value for ssh? If it set to `"check"` - try changing it to `"access"` and try to access your host via ssh.
If this work - I'll suggest to look into how to add 2FA into ssh client so it would show Tailscale's authentication link which is required in `"check"` mode.

Some links that helped me to investigate and fix similar issue:

- https://tailscale.com/kb/1193/tailscale-ssh/#ssh-access-rules-in-default-acl
- https://github.com/tailscale/tailscale/issues/4766